# How to use View Binding in Custom Dialog box layout?

Tags: android, android-viewbinding

I am having trouble in implementing view binding in a Custom Dialog Layout. Is it possible?

```
 private fun showCustomDialog(title: String) {
    val dialog = Dialog(activity)
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog.setCancelable(false)

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_layout)

    val body = dialog.findViewById(R.id.body) as TextView
    body.text = title

    val noBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.noBtn) as TextView
    yesBtn.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    val yesBtn = dialog.findViewById(R.id.yesBtn) as Button
    noBtn.setOnClickListener { dialog.dismiss() }
    dialog.show()

}
```

Answer (score 45):

It is possible.

```
CustomDialogBinding binding = CustomDialogBinding 
          .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getContext()));
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    builder.setView(binding.getRoot());
```

Where CustomDialogBinding is the name of the view binding file for your custom layout

kotlin

```
val bind :CustomDialogBinding = CustomDialogBinding .inflate(inflater)
dialog.setContentView(bind.root)
```

Comment: Nice! worked like charm

Answer (score 14):

**Code:**

```
val inflater = context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
val binding = CustomDialogLayoutBinding.inflate(inflater)
dialog.setContentView(binding.root)
```

Answer (score 4):

Example:

```
val dialogBinding = DialogCustomBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
dialog.setView(dialogBinding.root)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
 val winnerDBinding =WinnerDialougeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
 val dialog = Dialog(this);
 dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
 dialog.setCancelable(false)
 dialog.setContentView(winnerDBinding.root)

 winnerDBinding.btnPlayAgain.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this,MainActivity::class.java)
    finish()
    startActivity(intent)
 }
 dialog.show()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Similar way to the first answer, including a few extra lines. Assumes your binding is `DialogReviewBinding`.

```
val inflater = activity.layoutInflater
val dialogBinding = DialogReviewBinding.inflate(inflater)
val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity).create()
dialog.setView(dialogBinding.root)
dialog.show()
```

And this is surrounded by a `activity?.let { activity -> }` block

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience working on Android but I ran into this error and finally I was able to fix it.
Regarding your code, I think that should be something like this:

```
private fun showCustomDialog(title: String) {
    val dialog = Dialog(activity)
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    dialog.setCancelable(false)

    val dialogBinding = customLayoutBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    dialog.setContentView(this.dialogBinding.root)

    val body = dialogBinding.body
    val noBtn = dialogBinding.noBtn
    val yesBtn = dialogBinding.yesBtn

    body.text = title

    noBtn.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    yesBtn.setOnClickListener {
        dialog.dismiss()
    }

    dialog.show()
}
```